# Unwanted line when filled between two curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node[below]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, -2 ) -- (0, 4) node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[fill=lightgray, domain=0:1] plot(\x, {sqrt(\x)} ) -- (1, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \draw[line width=1.6pt, red] plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, {(\x)^2});
    \draw[line width=1.6pt, cyan] plot[smooth,domain=0:4] (\x, {sqrt(\x)});
    \draw[line width=1.6pt, cyan] plot[smooth,domain=0:4] (\x, {-sqrt(\x)});
    \draw (0, 0) node[below left]{$\mathrm{O}$};
    \draw (1, 1) node[above left]{$\mathrm{A}$};
    \draw[draw=none , fill=white , domain=0:1] plot(\x, {(\x)^2} ) -- (1, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \draw[black] (1, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

produces the following:

[image]

However, as you can say we have an undesired line depicted going from (1, 1) to (1, 0). Despite using the command `\draw=none` I can still not get rid of the line , although I do get why that line is there.

Any workarounds to get rid of the extra line?

**P.S:** I'm not interested in a pgfplots approach using the `\fillbetween` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the command

```
\draw[fill=lightgray, domain=0:1] plot(\x, {sqrt(\x)} ) -- (1, 0) -- (0, 0);
```

which draws a line from the last point of the parabola to the point (1,0). If you don't want this line change `\draw` for `\fill` or add the option `draw=none`.

Besides, I would change something else. Better to do draw the fillings before the lines, and you can draw the gray filling directly enclosed between the two parabolas, this way you don't need the white filling overlapped.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[lightgray, domain=0:1] plot(\x, {sqrt(\x)} ) -- plot (1- \x, {(1-\x)*(1-\x)});
    \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node[below]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, -2) -- (0, 4) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[line width=1.6pt, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, \x*\x);
    \draw[line width=1.6pt, cyan] plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x*\x, \x);
    \draw (0, 0) node[below left]{$\mathrm{O}$};
    \draw (1, 1) node[above left]{$\mathrm{A}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever your approach!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Using one curve only (the parabola) and the `even odd rule` option.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % the fill
  \draw[fill=lightgray] plot[smooth, domain=-1.5:1.5] (\x, {(\x)^2});
  \draw[fill=white, even odd rule]
  plot[smooth, domain=-2:2] (\x, {(\x)^2})
  plot[smooth, domain=-2:2] ({(\x)^2}, \x);

  % the curves
  \draw[red, line width=1.6pt] plot[smooth, domain=-2:2] (\x, {(\x)^2});
  \draw[cyan, line width=1.6pt] plot[smooth, domain=-2:2] ({(\x)^2}, \x);

  % the axes
  \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node[below]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -2 ) -- (0, 4) node[left]{$y$};

  % the points
  \draw (0, 0) node[below left]{$O$};
  \draw (1, 1) node[above left]{$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never quite understood what `even odd rule` does and when to use it!!

Comment: It counts the number of overlapping surfaces; if it is an even number, it does nothing; if it is an odd number, it fills the corresponding intersection.  In the above answer, I used it to recover the white color outside the intersection.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it!!